# Spring cloud config git refreshRate behaviour

Tags: spring-cloud-config

I am trying to setup Spring Cloud Config Server and want to enable auto refresh of properties based on changes to the backing git repository.

Below is the bootstrap.yml of the server.

```
server:
  port: 8080

spring:
  application:
    name: my-configserver
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        bootstrap: true
        git:
          uri: /Users/anoop/Documents/centralconfig
          refreshRate: 15
          searchPaths:  {application}/properties
    bus:
      enabled: true
```

As per the documentation ***spring.cloud.config.server.git.refreshRate*** determines

> how often the config server will fetch updated configuration data from
>   your Git backend

I see that the config clients are not notified of changes, when the configuration changes. I have not configured a git hook for this and was hoping that just setting the property would do the job.

Anoop

Answer (score 2):

Since you have configured the `refreshRate` property, whenever config client (other applications) call config server to fetch properties (this happens when either the application starts or application calls `/actuator/refresh` endpoint), they will get properties which were fetched 15 seconds (your refreshRate) old.

By default the `refreshRate` property is set to 0, meaning any time client applications ask for property config server will fetch latest from GIT.

I don't think there is any property which lets your client apps get notified in case of change/commits in the GIT. This is something your app needs to do by calling `actuator/refresh` endpoint. This can be done programmatically using some scheduler (though I wouldn't recommend that).

Answer (score 0):

By default, the config client just reads the properties in git repo at startup and not again.

You can actually have a way to workaround by force bean to refresh its configuration from the config server.

First, you need to add @RefreshScope annotation in the bean where config needs to be reloaded.

Second, enable spring boot actuator in application.yml of config client.

```
# enable dynamic configuration changes using spring boot actuator
management:
    endpoints:
        web:
            exposure:
                include: '*'
```

And then config a scheduled job (by using @Scheduled annotation with fixedRate,...). Of course, fixedRate should conform with refreshRate from config server.
And inside that job, it will execute the request as below:

> curl -X POST http://username:password@localhost:8888/refresh

Then your config client will be notified changes in config repo every fixRate interval.

Answer (score 0):

The property *spring.cloud.config.server.git.refreshRate* is configured in the **Config Server** and controls how frequently it is going to pull updates, if any, from Git. Otherwise, the Config Server's default behaviour is to connect to the Git repo only when some client requests its configuration.

```
Git Repo -> Config Server
```

It has no effect in the communication between the Config Server and its clients.

```
Config Server -> Spring Boot app (Config Server clients)
```

Spring Boot apps built with Config Server clients *pull* all configuration from the Config Server during their startup. To enable them to dynamically change the initially loaded configuration, you need to perform the following steps in your **Spring Boot apps** aka **Config Server clients**:

1. Include Spring Boot Actuator in the classpath, for example using Gradle:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
```

2. Enable the actuator *refresh endpoint* via the `management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=refresh` property
3. Annotate the Beans holding the properties in your code with `@RefreshScope`, for example:

```
@RefreshScope
@Service
public class BookService {
  @Value("${book.default-page-size:20}")
  private int DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE;
  //...
}
```

4. With the application running, commit some property change into the repo:

```
git commit -am "Testing property changes"
```

5. Trigger the updating process by sending a HTTP POST request to the *refresh endpoint*, for example (using [httpie](https://httpie.io) and assuming your app is running locally at the port 8080:

```
http post :8080/actuator/refresh
```

and the response should be something like below indicating which properties, if any, have changed

```
HTTP/1.1 200
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v3+json
Date: Wed, 30 Jun 2021 10:18:48 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

[
    "config.client.version",
    "book.default-page-size"
]
```